# Has anybody created a reusable PhpStorm Code Style settings export for Craft CMS?

Tags: editor, workflow

Craft's codebase has nicely consistent coding conventions. Pixel & Tonic even publishes some information about their [Coding Standards](https://github.com/pixelandtonic/CodingStandards).

PhpStorm allows you to enforce a [PHP Code Style](https://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/help/code-style-php.html) in the editor and allows you to [Import and Export Settings](https://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/help/exporting-and-importing-settings.html) which include *Code Style* in the list of options.

Has anybody shared PhpStorm Code Style settings that enforce the Craft Standards?